# Auth and ACL with condition in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, before-filter

I can't find a solution to my problem.
I have an CakePHP website using Auth Component and ACL component.
I do not want users who are not active to be able to log in.

I found that userScope in Auth component can do that.
So in my **AppController** inside the **beforeFilter**, i added this :

```
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);
```

Of course in my UserController beforeFilter, a call to the parent method is made.

However, this doesn't worj, I am still able to login in with a user who have active set to 0.
I think it might be because of ACL component ?

Here is my beforFilter in AppController

```
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
    if (!$this->Session->check('Auth.User'))
        $this->layout = 'identification';
    $this->Auth->allow('display');

    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'welcome');
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active' => 1);
    }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are U using cakePHP 2.0 or 1.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use is not valid with Cake 2. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Here is some code that should work:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('scope' => array('User.active' => 1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't make it, you can always use an alternative:

```
$user = $this->Auth->user();
if($user['User']['active'] == 0){
   $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
   $this->Session->setFlash('You are not active.');
}
```

Comment: Ok, i did the check after the $this->Auth->login() method, and if the user is not active, a call to $this->Auth->logout() is made and a redirect to a good layout too. But it's not rally great because I need to log the user in to log the user out. Not very good for security ...

Comment: I know that but it's the best shoot at this moment until you find a better solution and if you find it, feel free to post it here. :D